# cmph Minimal perfect hashing

Tags: hash, perfect-hash, universal-hashing

I've spent days trying to make the library work on my system.
The library has several algorithms which generate MPHFs.
My understanding of minimal hash function is, that when I hash two distinct keys using the MPHF, they'll return two different ids.
This does not seem to be the case with the 2 million keys that I've generated (integers, read as string by the algorithm). I've tried couple of algorithms that the library implements but all of them result in duplicate 'ids' for a lot of keys.

Here is what I've written:

```
#include <cmph.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    FILE *fp = fopen("keys.txt", "r");
    FILE *read = fopen("keys2.txt", "r");
    ofstream ids("ids2.txt");

    if(!fp || !read || !ids.is_open()){
        cerr<<"Failed to open the file\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cmph_t* hash = NULL;
    // source of keys
    cmph_io_adapter_t *source = cmph_io_nlfile_adapter(fp);
    cmph_config_t *config = cmph_config_new(source);
    cmph_config_set_algo(config, CMPH_BDZ);
    hash = cmph_new(config);
    cmph_config_destroy(config);

    char *k = (char *)malloc(sizeof(12));

    while(fgets(k, INT_MAX, read) != NULL){
        string key = k;
        unsigned int id = cmph_search(hash, k, (cmph_uint32)key.length());
        ids<<id<<"\n";
    }

    cmph_destroy(hash);
    cmph_io_nlfile_adapter_destroy(source);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(read);
    ids.close();
}
```

Shouldn't the ids be unique for every distinct key if the algorithm claims to generate a minimal perfect hash function? There are 2048383 keys. For my project I would need the ids to map from 0 to 2048382, since I plan to use a minimal perfect hash function.
I am not sure where I am going wrong with my understanding.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your `keys2.txt` contains keys that weren't part of the set that was used to generate your `hash`, then, by definition of the mphf, you'll get either duplicate hashes or, possibly, values out of your range. It's up to you to store all keys that were used to generate `hash` and then verify that the key that was passed to `cmph_search` was the same as the one that resulted in the hash/id returned by cmph_search